# How to Dynamically Update Label with TextBox As Input Changes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, loops

I have a spelling application that I am building in VB.Net, where I have a textbox receiving simple input (spelling words), and a label which will show the output. What I want to accomplish is when I enter something in the textbox, I can see it in my label - as I am typing into the textbox.

I will admit that I don't know what I'm doing, as I've never tried this before, so I don't know to begin in terms of setting up what I need to do. I know that I'll need some variable to hold my String input, and will probably need some type of loop, but beyond that, I am lost. The only other example is in C#, and doesn't help me any.

Can anyone give me a simple model to work off of, so I can put the approach into memory? For now, all I have is code stub from my `TextChanged` event handler:

```
Private Sub txtSpell_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSpell.TextChanged
    'Set variables to hold values.
    Dim someText As String

    'Connect the label and textbox.
    lblShowInput.Text = txtWordInput.Text

    'Process loop to populate the label from textbox input.

    for '(This is where I am lost on the approach)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that I'll need some variable to hold my String input, and will
>   probably need some type of loop

I don't think you'll need a loop, or the variable to hold the value.  You almost have it:

```
Private Sub txtSpell_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSpell.TextChanged
    'Connect the label and textbox.
    lblShowInput.Text = txtSpell.Text
End Sub
```

In the code you provided, you are referencing an object named `txtWordInput` inside your `txtSpell` text changed event handler.  If you are entering the text in the `txtWordInput` input, you'll want to handle this in the `txtWordInput textChanged` event handler:

```
Private Sub txtWordInput_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtWordInput.TextChanged
        'Connect the label and textbox.
        lblShowInput.Text = txtWordInput.Text
End Sub
```

---

### **Follow-up**:

- The [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event is the correct event for this.
- In your code, you are assigning `lblShowInput.Text` to `txtWordInput.Text`, **but in the `txtSpell TextChanged` event handler.**
- You want to be in the TextChanged event handler for whatever `TextBox` you would like to use to update the label, as the text is *changing*.

To give a better example, I have created a simple `Winforms VB` application that has only a textbox named **InputTextBox** and a `label` named **Output Label**.

### **The Form:**

[image: Simple VB Form with textbox and label]

### **The Code:**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub InputTextBox_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles InputTextBox.TextChanged
        OutputLabel.Text = InputTextBox.Text

    End Sub
End Class
```

### **Explanation:**

- `InputTextBox_TextChanged` is the method name generated by Visual Studio for our event handler
- `Handles InputTextBox.TextChanged` ties the method to an actual event it is handling.
- When the `InputTextBox` text property is changed (typically by user input), whatever we have in our `InputTextBox_TextChanged Sub` will execute.   In this case, I am assigning the `Text` of `OutputLabel` to the `Text` of the `InputTextBox`

### **Output:**

[image]

### **Resources:**

- I've uploaded this simple demo to [GitHub](https://github.com/lreading/SampleVBTextChanged) if you'd like a closer look.
- Take a look at the [TextChanged documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx)

Comment: You have me greatly confused. Why would I substitute `txtSpell.Text` with `txtWordInput.Text`? They are essentially the same thing here. Perhaps I wrote the question wrong.

What I'm looking to do is have a user type some input into the "one textbox." This input will be a single word. As the user is typing into the textbox, I want the input to appear in a label I have for it to appear - `lblShowInput`. 

So I'm wondering wouldn't I have have to use something like the `OnKeyPress` event? This is what I'm trying to do, and have never used it before, so I don't know how I would set this up.

Comment: You should be using which ever `textbox` you want to use to update the `label`.  `txtSpell` is presumably some `textbox` on your form, and `txtWordInput` is presumably another `textbox` (Though I can't tell from this code).  They are not and *cannot* be the same thing.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: YOU HAVE HELPED ME SEE THE ERROR OF MY WAYS... DETAILS COUNT! Thank you so much, but I feel like an idiot. I looked at your answer, and then looked at my code and saw that I have a `Sub` for `lblShowInput` Label, and had it receiving the input from the textbox... no wonder it wouldn't work and you were right -- I did almost have it. Thanks for the confidence. 

Soon as I deleted the unnecessary `Sub` voila! It worked. Thanks again - this underscores that I'm over thinking sometimes. Trying to stop doing that.